# JavaScript RegEx - Validate 3 alphanumeric characters followed by or following wildcard

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate some fields on a form where I need to check if the user entered at least three characters before or after a wildcard(`*`).

For example: `*ABC` or `AB1*`

This is what I have:

```
var pattern = /^(\*\w{3})|(\w{3}\*)$/;

var matchArray = strInput.match(pattern); // Is this format okay?
if (matchArray == null) {
    return false;
} 
if (strInput.match(pattern)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    alert("You must enter at least three characters before or after a wildcard(*)\n For example- *ABC or ABC*");
}
```

`matchArray` contains `[*112,*112,]`. `matchArray` is having 3 groups `[0]=*112,[1]=*112, [2]= undefined`.

Is there something wrong with my grouping? Or did I add the OR operator correctly.

Comment: no because any group from 2nd or third can be empty due to alternation..use `^(\*\w{3}|\w{3}\*)$`..you need to escape `*` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put both `\*\w{3}` and `\w{3}\*` into one Capture Group (and have the OR inside that one), like so:

```
^\*\w{3}|\w{3}\*$
```

What was happening before was either `\*\w{3}` or `\w{3}\*` was actually matching the string, however each one was in a separate Capture Group. This means which one matched also depended on the Capture Group it was stored in.

So:

- `*ABC` would be stored in the **`1st` Capture Group** (it matches the first pattern, `\*\w{3}`)
- `ABC*` would be stored in the **`2nd` Capture Group** (it matches the second pattern, `\w{3}\*`)

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/pP1nC3/1)</kbd>

Comment: I tried var pattern = /^(\*\w{3}|\w{3}\*)$/; matchArray = [*123,*123]

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: my matchArray returned 2 matches --- matchArray = [*123,*123], it should match only 1 group.

Comment: Yes, you use `matchArray[1]` to get the `[1]st` group. The item at `[0]` is the whole match (it would contain other data if we had it outside the `1st` capture group). If you want only one item, just use `^\*\w{3}$|^\w{3}\*$` (you will get an array containing one item), though I really do not see the problem with using `matchArray[1]`

Comment: this worked for me.     var pattern = /^\*\w{3}$|^\w{3}\*$/;  Thanks for the help.

Comment: We don't need grouping for this, I removed the grouping from my original regex and that worked for me.  like this   var pattern = /^*\w{3}$|^\w{3}*$/;

Answer (score 1):

Your wildcard `*` must be escaped:

```
 /^(\*\w{3})|(\w{3}\*)$/
```

Otherwise it's a quantifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sometimes we are too lazy for doing that

Answer (score 0):

There are two capturing groups present in your alternation. If one is matched the other remains `undefined`. You should rather use

```
^(\*\w{3}|\w{3}\*)$
```

*JS Code*

```
var re = /^(\*\w{3}|\w{3}\*)$/g; 
var str = '*ABC';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
      re.lastIndex++;
   } 
   print(m[0] + "\n" + m[1]);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/xV4sd6)**

```js
var re = /^(\*\w{3}|\w{3}\*)$/; 
var str = '*ABC';

var result = str.match(re);
document.writeln(result[0] + '<br>');
document.writeln(result[1] + '<br>');
```